# Ошибка при установке GIMP: "ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd"

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, dpkg

Устанавливаю gimp по рекомендации: [sudo apt-get install gimp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-the-latest-gimp-version-available)

```
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
```

на жестком диске установлен интерпретатор python не из репозитория дистрибутива.

Comment: весьма похоже на то, что у вас в системе стоит интерпретатор python не из репозитория дистрибутива.

Comment: хотя возможно и: https://bugs.debian.org/783777 https://bugs.debian.org/783753

Comment: почему нету в списке Ubuntu Software?

Comment: на жестком диске установлен интерпретатор python не из репозитория дистрибутива.

Answer (score 1):

> на жестком диске установлен интерпретатор python не из репозитория дистрибутива

это, скорее всего, и вызывает ошибку в пост-инсталляционном скрипте пакета `python-minimal` (написанном, вероятно, на языке *python*).

как обходное средство можно временно подменить интерпретатор *python* на ту версию, которая идёт вместе с дистрибутивом.

на данный момент это, скорее всего, версия 2.7. уточинть можно, например, в списке зависимостей пакета `python-minimal` (приведён и пример вывода):

```
$ apt-cache show python-minimal | grep ^Depends:
Depends: python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.9-1~), dpkg (>= 1.13.20)
```

зависимость здесь — от пакета `python2.7-minimal`, в состав которого должен входить файл `/usr/bin/python2.7` (с интерпретатором версии, понятно, 2.7).

если такой файл действительно присутствует у вас на диске, вы можете сделать символическую ссылку на него в каталоге `/usr/local/sbin` с именем `python`:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/sbin/python
```

и, так как этот каталог (`/usr/local/sbin`) перечислен первым в переменной окружения `$PATH` для пользователя *root*, именно он и будет вызываться (при необходимости) во время выполнения идущих с пакетами пост-/пре- [де]инсталляционных скриптов.

---

а после удачной установки можете удалить эту символическую ссылку (до следующего раза, когда она вам может понадобиться):

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/sbin/python
```

---

**чуть более «автоматизированное» решение**:

можно сконфигурировать *apt* так, чтобы **перед** вызовом программы *dpkg* (которая непосредственно и занимается установкой/удалением/настройкой пакетов) эта символическая ссылка создавалась автоматически, а **после** вызова — удалялась.

для этого создайте в каталоге `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` файл с произвольным именем, начинающийся с цифр `99` (например, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99pythonsymlink`) такого, примерно, содержания:

```
DPkg {
    Pre-Invoke { "ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/sbin/python || true"; };
    Post-Invoke { "rm /usr/local/sbin/python || true"; };
};
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 ошибка с установкой gimp осталась subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: а предложение по второй из ссылок, которую я дал в комментарии, вы пробовали? `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-*/_sysconfigdata_nd.py /usr/lib/python2.7/`